# Close a PseudoTTY created via pty.openpty()

Tags: python, linux, tty, pty

I'm using `pty.openpty()` to fool a subprocess that changes its behaviour based on `isatty()`, vaguely like this:

```py
import pty
import subprocess

master, slave = pty.openpty()
with subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=slave) as process:
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

However, after doing this many many times (as part of automated testing), I get:

```
E           OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files

../../miniconda/envs/aclimatise-test/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py:1393: OSError
```

and

```
E       OSError: out of pty devices
../../miniconda/envs/aclimatise-test/lib/python3.7/pty.py:59: OSError
```

For some reason the `pty` module documentation doesn't tell me how or when to close the pseudoTTYs that I'm allocating. How and when should I do so? Or am I using `pty` in entirely the wrong way?

If it helps, I'm on Python 3.6+, using Linux (which I think is a requirement for using this module).

Comment: I've never worked with this, but can you maybe send a `Ctrl+d` or a `logout` to the pseudo-terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use os.close to close master and slave.

> os.close(fd) Close file descriptor fd.
>
> Note This function is intended for low-level I/O and must be applied
>   to a file descriptor as returned by os.open() or pipe(). To close a
>   “file object” returned by the built-in function open() or by popen()
>   or fdopen(), use its close() method.

Answer (score 1):

try setting `close_fds=True` in `subprocess.Popen`

```py
subprocess.Popen(
  # ...
  close_fds=True,
)
```